# c++ pointer to a Structure whose member is a pointer

Tags: c++

Hi all I am working on an assignment , when given a struct and its members         I will have to intialise the members using dynamic memory allocation . This is   the code I have used:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;
```

Structure

```
struct Student
{
char * name;
float gpa;
} ;
```

PROTOTYPES

```
Student *  createStudent(char name[], float gpa);

int main ()
{
 int length ;
 float gpa ;
 char *p;
 Student *myPointer ;
 Student myStudent ;
 myPointer = &myStudent;

 cout << " Please enter number of characters you want to enter " << endl;
 cin >> length ;
 length = length + 1;
 p= new char [length +1];
 cout << " Please enter name " << endl;
 cin >> p ;
 cout << " please enter gpa "<< endl;
 cin >> gpa ;
 myPointer = createStudent (p,gpa);
 cout << myPointer->gpa;
 cout << (*myPointer).name << endl;
```

Her's the error when printing the name, but when i see the value of the name before printing it is showing the same as entered by the user:

```
  delete[]p;
  p = 0;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
 }
```

This function creates a student object and assigns name and gpa as passed to the student object and returns a pointer of the student object:

```
Student *  createStudent( char name[], float gpa )
{

Student *studentPtr ;
Student studentObject;
studentPtr = &studentObject;
studentPtr-> name = name;
studentPtr-> gpa = gpa ;
return studentPtr ;
}
```

Can anyone give me an idea of why the name is not printing. Thank you in advance .

Comment: In `createStudent`, you are returning a pointer to a variable that goes out of scope at the end of the function. Using that pointer is undefined behavior, and could do anything.

Comment: It's remarkable how these assignments teach students (or learners otherwise) ways to code in C++ that one should *never* use in real world codebases

Comment: Indeed. Divya, you should be aware this course is teaching you to write _awful_ code. If you have no choice but to pass it, it would be worth reading about good practice in your own time, to avoid the bad habits sticking.

Comment: @gd1 Yeah, you'd think they were trying to protect their jobs through obfuscation or something.

Comment: Actually, after taking a couple years of comp science, I asked an electrical engineering programming instructor why he wasn't teaching pointers. His response was something along the lines of, "I don't need them." Had to work on real code for a while to figure out he wasn't nuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`studentObject` is allocated on the stack, i.e. it has automatic storage duration, which means it will be destroyed when the function returns. The pointer doesn't keep it alive.

That means `myPointer` is a dangling pointer; dereferencing it (`myPointer->`) invokes undefined behavior.

---

To correct it, simply return the object by value:

```
Student createStudent(char name[], float gpa)
{
    Student studentObject;
    studentPtr.name = name;
    studentPtr.gpa = gpa;
    return studentObject;
}
```

and

```
Student myStudent = createStudent(p, gpa);
```

---

**Edit:** I just read that you need to initialize the members using dynamic memory allocation. The above solution doesn't do that. For dynamic memory allocation you have to use `new`:

```
Student* createStudent(char name[], float gpa)
{
    Student* studentPtr = new Student;
    studentPtr->name = name;
    studentPtr->gpa = gpa;
    return studentPtr;
}
```

and

```
myPointer = createStudent(p, gpa);
// use
delete myPointer;
```

It would probably be a good idea to also allocate a new buffer for `studentPtr->name` with `new`, instead of just assigning the pointer; you can see *Mateusz*'s answer about that.

But of course this is just a bad example from your professor. As mentioned by *gd1*, this kind of code is not good modern C++ and shouldn't end up in real production code.

Comment: Oh I got it but how do I correct this error . Will i have to declare the student object in the main .

Comment: @zenith The odds are, the professor/teacher will tell him/her to return a pointer, and he/she'll be forced to use `new`. From bad to worse ;)

Comment: Yes I was asked to make the function pointer returning function . But I am eager to  see if there is really any way to do that .

Comment: Of course you were asked, its standard practice to teach these appalling ideas. Learn about `new`/`delete` for this assignment, and then forget about them. ;)

Comment: @DivyaSankar So where's the code to allocate memory for the name part of the Student object?!

Comment: Yeah this is working and also got my doubts cleared . Thank you .

Comment: If a pointer returned from a function is no longer valid after returning the function (as it is local to that function ). How does a function returning pointer be useful ?

Comment: @DivyaSankar It's because the pointer (the pointer itself, not what it points to) is copied from inside the function, instead of returning a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally wrong:

```
Student* createStudent( char name[], float gpa )
{
    Student *studentPtr ;
    Student studentObject;
    studentPtr = &studentObject;
    studentPtr-> name = name;
    studentPtr-> gpa = gpa ;
    return studentPtr ;
}
```

`studentObject` is a local object, that is destroyed just after the function ends. Returning pointers and/or references to local variables is an error - you should get warning from your compiler.

Another issue is this line:

`studentPtr->name = name;`

What you do now: allocate a block of memory in `main()`, pass it to an object, that may use this memory and then free it in `main()`. You should not do that - objects should be responsible for their content. Are you sure, that this responsibility should be yours? I would suggest you to:

```
Student* createStudent( char name[], float gpa )
{
    size_t name_len = strlen(name);
    Student studentObject;
    studentObject.name = new char[name_len+1];
    strncpy(studentObject.name, name, name_len + 1);
    studentObject.gpa = gpa ;
    return studentObject;
}
```

And analogical function to destroy `Student`:

```
void destroyStudent(Student* student)
{
    delete[] student->name;
    student->name = nullptr;
}
```

Obvious solution would be to use `std::string`, but I assume, that you have a good reason to do all this manually... don't you?

Oh, and if you **really** need to return `Student` as pointer:

```
Student* createStudent( char name[], float gpa )
{
    size_t name_len = strlen(name);
    Student* studentPtr = new Student;
    studentPtr->name = new char[name_len+1];
    strncpy(studentPtr->name, name, name_len + 1);
    studentPtr-> gpa = gpa ;
    return studentPtr;
}

void destroyStudent(Student* student)
{
    delete[] student->name;
    student->name = nullptr;
    delete[] student;
}
```